# jQuery .text('') on multiple nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to remove all text from html and print only tags. I Ended up writing this:

```
var html = $('html');
var elements = html.find('*');
elements.text('');
alert(html.html());
```

It only out prints `<head></head><body></body>`. Was not that suppose to print all tags. I've nearly 2000 tags in the html.

Comment: (`html` is a reserved term, use other terms) it isn't, sorry for the quick trigger.

Comment: Is it? I'm *sure* I've used `html` as a variable name before (and, so far as I can recall, gotten away with it...)

Comment: @Uzair, the problem is that setting the inner text to the empty string will also remove all the descendant elements. Do you have any way to filter the elements you want to clear (e.g. are they all paragraphs)?

Comment: You'll probably have to recursively look at child elements and set their text to nothing.

Comment: Why do you need that...?

Comment: when you call the element `html.find('*')` and then remove all text you may be emptying out much of the body content.  alert the elements list, or dump them to the console to see what was actually affected.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I want to remove all text in all elements but not elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var elements = html.find('*');
elements.text('');
```

That says "find all elements below `html`, then empty them". That includes `body` and `head`. When they are emptied, there are no other elements on the page, so they are the only ones that appear in `html`'s content.

If you really wnat to remove all text from the page and leave the elements, you'll have to do it with DOM methods:

```
html.find('*').each(function() {               // loop over all elements
    $(this).contents().each(function() {       // loop through each element's child nodes
        if (this.nodeType === 3) {             // if the node is a text node
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this); // remove it from the document
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Do you really need the first `.each()`?

Comment: The line ' $(this).contents().each(function() {' is throwing eror 'cannot get object document of null'.

Comment: @UzairFarooq [It works, so far as I can tell.](http://jsfiddle.net/kcuDe/) Could you provide a sample of the markup that doesn't work? What browser are you using?

Comment: `html = $(html).clone();  
var elements = html.find('*');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; ++i) {
    var elemNodes = $(elements[i]).contents();
    for (var j=0; j<elemNodes.length; ++j) {
       if (elemNodes[j].nodeType === 3)
           elemNodes[j].parentNode.removeChild(elemNodes[j]);
    }
}`

Comment: So does that work, or doesn't it? Can you provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net that shows the code not working? Psychic debugging is hard...

Comment: Throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null. It's on the line `var elemNodes = $(elements[i]).contents();`

Comment: Got it working. The html was extracted from an iframe while context of $ was not that iframe. I used the correct context and it worked fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You just deleted everything from your dom:

```
$('html').find('*').text('');
```

This will set the text of all nodes inside the `<html>` to the empty string, deleting descendant elements - the only two nodes that are left are the two children of the root node, `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` with their empty text node children - exactly the result you got.

If you want to remove all text nodes, you should use this:

```
var html = document.documentElement;
(function recurse(el) {
    for (var i=0; i<el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = el.childNodes[i];
        if (child.nodeType == 3)
            el.removeChild(child);
        else
            recurse(child);
    }
})(html);
alert(html.outerHTML);
```

Comment: The recursive method is of course the nice way, so +1, but I believe named function expressions will not behave as expected in old IE...

Comment: Afaik it will only create an additional global, but behave correctly - I won't care about IE

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$(function(){

    var elements = $(document).find("*");

    elements.each(function(index, data){
        console.log(data);
    });

});
```

This will return all the html elements of page.

Answer (score 0):

lonesomeday seems to have the right path, but you could also do some string rebuilding like this:

```
    var htmlString=$('html').html();
    var emptyHtmlString="";
    var isTag=false;

for (i=0;i<htmlString.length;i++)
{
    if(htmlString[i]=='<')
        isTag=true;
    if(isTag)
    {
        emptyHtmlString+=htmlString[i];
    }
    if(htmlString[i]=='>')
        isTag=false;
}
alert(emptyHtmlString);
```